# Polymer 1.0 paper-input datetime-local type not displayed at all in FF or Safari

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm having issues with just one field in my form.  I have a paper-input that the type is set to datetime-local.  In some browsers this displays fine, Chrome, Samsung's Browser,Opera.  However, in Firefox and Safari it does not show up and the user can't even enter anything into the field.  How can I get this to show up without using a non-paper input?(it shows up when I use a normal input just refused to show when I use a paper one) All my other elements show up fine in all browsers, just this datetime-local one is what's messing it up.  Anyone have any ideas on how to get around this while maintaining the material look?

Comment: Did you finally resolve it?

Comment: I actually ended up using a custom polymer date and time picker element: https://github.com/bendavis78/paper-time-picker/ https://github.com/bendavis78/paper-date-picker/

Answer (score 0):

A `<paper-input>` polymer element is just [creating a generic `<input>` control in its template](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/master/paper-input.html#L73). The behaviour you have is not related with Polymer but with the  html5.

As you can read in the [documentation from w3](
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_datetime-local.asp) for the input DateTime local object:

> Note:  elements with type="datetime-local" are not supported in
>   Internet Explorer or Firefox.